# Is there a sense in which $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is "free"?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Given a set $S$, the free group on $S$ consists of finite strings of elements in $S$. They can be visualized as paths on the integer grid $\mathbb{Z}^S$ starting at the origin, with the group operation given by path concatenation.

There is no set for which $\mathbb{R}$ is the corresponding free group- however it is tempting to view $\mathbb{R}$ as a free group on a single "infinitesimal generator". More generally given a set $S$ we could consider the group where

- elements are pairs $(T, f)$ with $T \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f: [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^S$ a continuous function and $f(0)=0$. (The value of $T$ mirrors the length of a string in the free group. )
- the product of $(T_1,f_1)$ with $(T_2,f_2)$ is a map $[0,T_1+T_2]\to\mathbb{R}^S$ given by $f_1(t)$ for  $t \in [0,T_1)$ and $f_1(T_1)+f_2(t-T_1)$ for $t\in[T_1, T_1 + T_2]$
- the identity element is $(0,0\mapsto 0)$,

In a commutative version of this definition, as in the free commutative group, two paths would be equal if they have the same start and end point.

Does this construction have a name? I see there is infinitesimal generators in the context of Lie groups, but that does not seem to be related...

Edit: the paths should also be equivalent up to reparameterization.

Comment: The group operator is a binary operation, so there really isn't a way to add infinitely many elements. So an infinitesimal just generates infinitesimals.

Comment: If you allow infinite sums, you get the problem of non-absolutely convergent sums. Then $1-1/2+1/3-\cdots$ converges to different values depending on the order.

Comment: In any event, there are no infinitesimal elements of the real numbers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that is why I avoid infinitesimals in the definition

Comment: Maybe you could think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the free Abelian Lie group? (this really isn't a topic I know much about)

Comment: If $S$ is not finite, then the maps $S\to\mathbb Z$ do not form the free abelian group on $S.$ The free abelian group is a subgroup.

Comment: In the end, you seem to be talking about a vector space over $\mathbb R,$ rather than a free abelian group.

Comment: Granting for sake of argument that the notion of "free group on an infinitesimal generator" does make sense, why would you expect the resulting group to be $\Bbb R$ rather than $\Bbb Q$?  (This is not a criticism, it's an attempt to take your idea seriously.)

Comment: I think the following is true: suppose $(G;*,\tau)$ is a *connected Hausdorff topological group*. Then for every $g\in G$ there is exactly one map of topological groups (= group homomorphism which is also continuous) from $(\mathbb{R};+, \tau_{\mathit{Euclidean}})$ to $G$ which sends $1$ to $g$. A la category theory, this is focusing on freeness "from the outside" - e.g. "the free [thing] on one generator" should be a [thing] $A$ together with an element $a$ such that for any *other* [thing] $B$ and any element $b\in B$ there is exactly one [thing]-morphism $A\rightarrow B$ sending $a$ to $b$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: That's not true--there are connected topological groups (even ones that are compact) that are not path-connected (for instance, solenoids).  Uniqueness can also fail (consider the circle group).

Comment: @EricWofsey Ouch, my mistake!

Comment: Well, free groups are precisely those groups acting freely on trees, and $\mathbb{R}$ acts freely on a useful generalisation of a tree called an [$\mathbb{R}$-tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_tree) (as do many other groups). [This smells slightly circular, but the point is the word "useful" in "useful generalisation".]